# jQuery Cookie Plugin Not Reading Entire Value of Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a cookie:

**Name:**
mycookie

**Value:**
ID=5

When using `$.cookie('mycookie')` and logging it:

```
var testCookie = $.cookie('mycookie');    
console.log(testCookie);
```

Only "**ID**" is displayed in the console. The "**=5**" does not show. Is this a limitation of the plugin, or am I missing something in order to get the entire "**ID=5**" value to display?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Using this http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html#jQuery-Cookie-plugin

```
            function getCookie(name) {
                var nameEQ = name + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
                }
                return null;
            }

           // Get my cookie
            var cookie =  getCookie('mycookie');


            console.log(cookie);
```

I was able to return "**ID=5**" in the console.

Look like it might be a limitation of the plugin, unless I'm missing an option or something...

Comment: What did you use to set the cookie?  If I use the plugin you're using to set a cookie to value `id=5` and then read it back, it's fine.  If I use my own cookie lib/plugin to set a similar cookie, and read it back with the plugin you're using, it is also fine. Whatever you're setting the cookie with needs to be URI encoding it so that the `=` doesn't confuse parsing routines.

Comment: Hmm, good call. The cookie is being set via a .NET POST. But, if URI encoding is the reason, why is it that my second method, without the plugin, reads the cookie just fine?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same question...not sure where to go from here really.  Setting the cookie with the JS lib you're using works with it and other libs. And I don't have a .NET setup to mimic what you're doing.